# MyBatis select returning String, string, cursor

Tags: java, stored-procedures, annotations, cursor, mybatis

I have a stored procedure that returns a `string(return_code), String(return_msg), cursor(p_out_refcursor)`.
The application is using annotation based

```
@Select("{ call SAMPLES.INSERT_T_SAMPLE ( "
        + "#{sampleId,jdbcType=INTEGER, mode=IN},"
        + "#{p_out_refcursor, jdbcType=SYS_REFCURSOR, mode=OUT}, "
        + "#{return_code, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT}, "
        + "#{return_msg, jdbcType=VARCHAR, mode=OUT}, )}"
);
public List<Sample> getSamplesById(@Param(value = "Id") String Id);
```

Would be happy to be able to get the List from the cursor

Comment: Please describe the specific technical problem. If there is an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide detailed information about what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the tour and read [ask] and its linked resources

Comment: @Amigma This executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56834806) might help. If it didn't, please add the related classes and the stored procedure definitions.